# Failed to read file attributes for assets.xcassets in Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode, assets

when i am trying to run the project in Xcode 9.1 it shows an error

Failed to read file attributes for assets.xcassets and stop.

Comment: thank you for your answer .

Comment: i try Pod install from the link you send me and the problem is solve.